how to use connection pool outside of request
I'd like to call a function every minute. I use connection pool and in a regular endpoint I can use req.app.locals.db.query('select 1) to query ms-sql database but in a function this won't work...
in server.js
const express = require('express');
const sql = require('mssql');
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const app = express();

require('./tools.js')()
const job = schedule.scheduleJob('*/1 * * * *', function(req,res){
    console.log('This job was supposed to run every 1 minute);
    tool1(); //function in tools.js
  });
appPool.connect().then((pool) => {
    app.locals.db = pool;
    console.log('Connected to database: '+config.database);

    const server = app.listen(process.env.APP_PORT, () => {
        const host = server.address().address;
        const port = server.address().port;
        console.log(' ' + process.env.APP_NAME + ' app listening at http://%s:%s ', host, port);
    });
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error creating connection pool', err);
});

in tools.js :
module.exports = function () {
    this.tool1 = function () {
        req.app.locals.db.query('SELECT 1'); // Error

    }
}


Things hanging off req are only available when the request is available. You need to pass it around, put in a module somewhere, etc, while still not using it before it’s prepared.

I tried to pass it but that doesn't work either.... tool1(req,res); this.tool1 = function (req,res)

Few experiments and I was able to achieve what I wanted... I'm posting the solution in case any other newbie like me is looking for similar thing...
Changes in server.js:
require('./tools.js')(app) //passing express app to tools.js file
const job1 = schedule.scheduleJob('*/1 * * * *', function(){
        console.log('tool1 - run every 1 minute. Kicked at ' + new Date());
        const {tool1} = require('./tools.js');
        tool1();
      });
    
    const job2 = schedule.scheduleJob('*/5 * * * *', function(){
        console.log('tool2 - run every 5 minutes. Kicked at ' + new Date());
        const {tool2} = require('./tools.js');
        tool2();
      });
  

Changes in tools.js:
module.exports = (app) => {
    const tool1 = function () {
        app.locals.db.query(`Select 1 `, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                 console.log(err)
              } else {
                 console.log('works 1');
                 }
            })
    const tool2 = function() {
        app.locals.db.query(`Select 2 `, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                  console.log(err)
              } else {
                  console.log('works 2');
               }
            })
    }
module.exports = { tool1, tool2 }; //must be after function inicialization
}

